# JSTL Conditional Operator with variable

Tags: foreach, jstl

While working on jstl tags I came across foreach loop:

```
<c:forEach items="#{data.steps}" var="item" varStatus="status">
        <li><a href="" class="${status.index == '1'? 'current' : ''}">#{item}</a></li>          
    </c:forEach>
```

How can I replace the static '1' (status.index == '1') with an variable? Should look like: status.index == '1' == #{data.step}?

Answer (score 0):

Let say you want to replace constant '1' with a variable name 'step' existing in page/request/session/application scope. Here is the code:

```
<a href="" class='${status.index == step ? "current" : ""}'>
```

If step is a property of a bean 'beanA' existing page/request/session/application scope scope. You can code like this

```
<a href="" class='${status.index == beanA.step ? "current" : ""}'>

// beanA has a method getStep().
```